# How can I get Hpricot to play nice with HTML5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, hpricot

I am using Hpricot to parse a theme file. I have noticed, however, that if I feed a valid HTML5 document into Hpricot(), it auto-closes HTML5 tags (like `<section>`), and messes with the `DOCTYPE`.

Are there any extensions to Hpricot, or perhaps a flag I need to set, that will allow HTML5 documents to be parsed correctly?

Comment: It also has issues with self-closing img tags. See my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220795

Comment: Could you add a small example of a file you are trying to parse, demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use Hpricot, as opposed to Nokogiri? The latter is actively developed/maintained and has become a very standard part of the ruby toolkit for these sorts of things.

Answer (score 2):

I know it kind of works around the direct question but I would suggest you try Nokogiri http://nokogiri.org/ as mentioned in some of the comments on your question post. I've had no issues with it parsing any HTML/XML like structured text, including HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

I think Hpricot's [to_original_html](http://rubydoc.info/github/hpricot/hpricot/master/Hpricot/Traverse#to_original_html-instance_method) method is exactly what you're looking for.

From the docs, to_original_html

> Attempts to preserve the original HTML of the document, only outputing new tags for elements which have changed.