# Issue with unclosed img tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri, hpricot

data presented in HTML format and submitted to server, that does some preprocessing.

It operates with "src" attribute of "img" tag.

After preprocessing and saving, all the preprocessed "img" tags are not self-closed.

For example, if "img" tag was following:

```
<img src="image.png" />
```

after preprocessing with Nokogiri or Hpricot, it will be:

```
<img src="/preprocessed_path/image.png">
```

The code is pretty simple:

```
doc = Hpricot(self.content)
doc.search("img").each do |tag|
  preprocess tag
end
self.content = doc.to_html
```

For Nokorigi, it looks the same.

How to resolve this issue ?

---

**Update 1**

Forget to mention - i have HTML 5 page, which i'm trying to validate with [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check).

When "img" tag is inside a div, it complaints about following:

```
required character (found d) (expected i)
</div>
```

For example, try to validate following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="image.png">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You will get the same error:

```
Line 9, Column 4: required character (found d) (expected i)
</div>
```

Comment: In the preprocess function you are delegating to, do you not have control over each `img` tag? Can you not return what it is already return and append an explicit `</img>` close tag?

Comment: Sure, i can parse everything by hands, using sophisticated regular expressions etc. But, this task must be up to library, i'm using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is with your `<html>` tag where it declares the `XMLNS` attribute as `"XHTML"`. This seems like it would be contradictory to the fact that it's not an XHTML document. If you remove this XMLNS attribute, it should be valid.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>something here</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <img src="image.png">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, Thanks! I'm completely forgot about this namespace. It was left after copy-paste, that was done many months ago.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your libraries are generating correct HTML, and the trailing "/" is not correct in HTML.

Unless you're serving `application/xhtml+xml`, there's no point in having it there at all. The IMG tag is self-closing in all versions of HTML, and the "/" is meaningless.

If you *are* serving `application/xhtml+xml`, I think you'll need to explicitly use Nokogiri's `to_xhtml`.

Comment: @AntonAL: So you are serving XHTML instead of HTML. Like I said, in that case, you will need to generate XHTML instead of HTML. Or use HTML. You just need to pick one and stick with it.